# SharePoint 2010 User Code Host service stops

Tags: 2010, deployment, sandbox-solution, solution-deployment

When I try to deploy any SandBox Solution I receive following error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Retract Solution': Timeout occurred while running the SharePoint Sandboxed Code service. This service is required to run sandboxed solutions in SharePoint. Please ensure the service is configured correctly in SharePoint.

Each time I try to deploy a SandBox solution, `SharePoint 2010 User Code Host Service` stops.

Why it happen and how can I deploy a SandBox Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a sequence magic!

1. In *Windows Services*, check `Sharepoint Timer Service`, start it if it's not running
2. In Windows Services, check `SharePoint 2010 User Code Host`, start it if it's not running
3. DO NOT DEPLOY!
4. In Central Admin>Services on Server, find "`Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service`", and start it.
5. Deploy it.

NOTES:

- if you skip step 1, steps 2 and 4 fails.
- if you skip step 2, step 4 fails.
- if you skip step 3, "SharePoint 2010 User Code Host" stops and deploy fails.
- if you skip step 4, "SharePoint 2010 User Code Host" stops and deploy fails.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out..
It may be problem of feature which you have to activate from Central Admin.

http://sp2010solutions.blogspot.in/2012/03/sandboxed-solution-error-occurred-in.html

Or you can check this

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/9259/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-activate-features-timeo.aspx

Comment: I checked them before. These are pointing to start the service in Services. I tried it, the service starts but stop on deployment process with no reason.